# allow webservice to be called from script

Tags: asp.net, webservice-client

hi there i have a demo page in my web site, i am learning how to call webservice from script
this is my page
http://applicazioni.vsc300.it/Mediweb2015/Prova.aspx

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {

                            
    var params = { 'IDPaziente': 6586 }
          $.ajax({
          "dataType": 'json',
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "type": "GET",       "url":"http://applicazioni.vsc300.it/Service.asmx/CercaPaziente",
         "data": params,
       "success": function (msg) {
   var json = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.d);
 //valorizza texbox
                                            $("#TXT_CognomePaziente").val(json.Denominazione);
          },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
               alert(error);
         }
        });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <input name="TXT_CognomePaziente" type="text" id="TXT_CognomePaziente" name="TXT_CognomePaziente" />
```

and this is the service:

```
' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
 Public Class Service
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService


    '   <WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, Method = "GET")>
    <WebMethod()> _
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
    Public Function CercaPaziente(IDPaziente As Integer) As String
        Dim serialiser As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()

        Dim Paz As New CLS_Paziente
        Paz.GetCercaAnagrafica(IDPaziente)

        Dim serializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim serializedItems As String = serializer.Serialize(Paz)

        Return serializedItems
    End Function

End Class
```

it returns an error, that **Only Web services with a [ScriptService] attribute on the class definition can be called from script.**
but i enabled it!!! 
what can i do?

Comment: Can you show your javascript call to this webservice?

Comment: ok i did :D
before there was just a link to my test page, now i added javascript code here on the question

Comment: did you fix this already?

Comment: yes i did
it works very nice now

Comment: you should post your solution here for others take help.

Answer (score 0):

From [this doc](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vbnut_8/index1.html):

> If more than one attribute is applied to a single program element, the attributes are enclosed in a single set of angle brackets and delimited from one another by a comma. For example:

```
<Obsolete(), WebMethod()> 
Public Function PageCount(strURL As String) As Integer
```

(This was hard to find, by the way.  I couldn't find it anywhere on MSDN.)  So, this isn't what your code does, and the .NET compiler is probably ignoring your attributes altogether.  Try this and see if it works:

```
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService(), _
WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/"), _
WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1), _
Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Public Class Service
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
```